# Add btrfs root parition entry to Grub2

Tags: 11.10, grub2, btrfs

I have a separate 10GB partition to test pre-release builds. This time I decided to test the btrfs as root. After finishing installation, ubiquity showed an error message stating that grub could not be installed and I must install it manually. I thought 11.10 supported grub on btrfs. Anyways, here is my partition scheme.

```
/dev/sda1 ext4 / (Oneiric)
/dev/sda2 ext4 /home 
/dev/sda3 btrfs / (Oneiric)
```

The problem is that grub does not pick up /dev/sda3 entries using update-grub2 command.

How do I manually add an entry for /dev/sda3 to grub2 so that I can choose which installation to boot into?

Comment: possibly you need a separate /boot partition as per this bug report? https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/23901

Comment: @fossfreedom, nope, grub2 now supports booting directly from btrfs.  Owais Lone, when you installed you had sda3 set to mount at / right?  sda1 should not have been assigned a mount point.

Comment: @psusi Yes, /dev/sda3 was selected as /. No mount point was selected to /dev/sda1. I installed twice with the same result.

Comment: Do you want the btrfs-oneiric to appear in your sda1 grub? Do you have `os-prober` installed on your sda1 system?

Comment: Yes it's installed. Anyways, I reformatted the partition to ext4 and installed precise on it but an answer might help someone else in the same situation.